# Price Optimization from Data

Tags: econometrics, elasticity, optimization, applied-econometrics, price

How can I find the optimal price that maximizes profits, given past sales data?  I thought I could do this, but I've been running into problems.

Data:

```
Price, Quantity Sold, Unit Cost
$90, 1100, $10
$100, 1000, $10
```

I can find elasticity (-0.82) and I've been reading some things that say that you can find the optimal price, but I've only been able to tell the direction the price should be moved.  [This answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-is-price-elasticity-determined-in-practice/67) says use the Lerner condition, but that just shows if elasticity < -1 decrease and if elasticity > -1 increase price.  And [this article](http://www.digitopoly.org/2014/07/30/amazon-makes-its-case-against-hachette/) says `what is much harder to do (although there are structural techniques to do so) is to work out what the optimal price should be`

edit to add:
I can find the linear equation for demand based on these 2 data points and find the point that maximizes revenue.  I also found a demand function equation Qd=Qh*((P/Ph)^Ed), where Qd is the predicted Quantity Demand, Qh is observed Quantity, Ph is observed Price, Ed is Elasticity of Demand, and P is the independent variable price.  But are any of these the best method to use?

Comment: You can of course optimize price (in general). But I hope you have more data than that...

Comment: It's just a simple example. Can you link to any information on price optimization

Comment: There's so much... I would suggest you start by understanding optimization in general. There's no magic about price. You can optimize practically anything with appropriate data, price is just one application. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization

Comment: Thanks for the links. I know how to do optimization in general, but I haven't seen much specifics on the models used (other than the simple ones above)

Comment: Is it true in general that you can't extrapolate much from data? If you have pricing data from $5-$10 you couldn't tell if the optimal price is $12.50?

Comment: You can extrapolate somewhat with a given degree of uncertainty if you have rich data, but it's infinitely better to interpolate. As for examples, you'll find a ton of studies on scholar.google.com and there are lots of textbooks and chapters of textbooks on the topic. Price Theory by Milton Friedman is one. There's really a wealth of material. Here's a theoretical paper from Stanford http://web.stanford.edu/~yyye/convexpricingms.pdf

Comment: The Lerner condition described in the answer you have linked to in your question actually yields an exact optimal price, not just a direction.

Comment: @denesp The optimal price derived from that would be different when measuring from different price points, right?  So if in addition to the data above I found at P=110, Q=900. My optimal price calculation would be different if I measured the elasticity from 90 and 100, or 100 and 110, or 90 and 110.  Is there a way to use more than 2 data points?  Or would you just use the min and max price points? Is this way better than trying to model the demand curve from data points?  Thanks

Comment: Also, what if elasticity > -1?

Comment: @Adam12344 I am not sure I understand your comments. (Consider editing your question to clarify.) A lot depends on how you model your demand function. Unless you specifically modell a demand function which has constant price elasticity price elasticity will not be constant and you can set a $p$ for which $\epsilon(p) = -1$. If price elasticity is constant and it is not equal to $-1$ then you have no revenue maximizing price but using the Lerner condition you may still have a profit maximizing price.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to start from the extreme. For example, when price set $1000, zero sales; $500 two sales on the higher price side equation. To the other, price $10, 10,000 sales; price $50, 300 sales. In this way, come out with a figure that maximizes revenue.